# cin, getline, leading whitespace: ignore vs ws

Tags: c++, iostream

So every once in a while, when I read documentation for getline, I get reminded of the infamous whitespace issue. Yes, I know what it is. This question is about the supposedly standard solution

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Meanwhile, I was always using

```
std::cin >> std::ws;
```

The difference between the two being mainly mine one does also ignore whitespace at the beginning of the line. That said, for many uses it is sufficient or equivalent, and arguably simpler to remember.

So why do people always recommend the first one? Not knowing about both? Finding those spaces precious by default?

Comment: That's a standard solution? To what problem?

Comment: The two do different things if the input is something like `123abc\n...`.

Comment: Most people don't know about `std::ws` and the difference between it and `ignore()` which is the main reason.

Comment: The two do different things. Sometimes either of them will do what you want. Other times (like when you want to be able to input spaces before a string) only the first one will do what you need. A good thing about the stream functions is that you can chain them together to form mini parsers. When you do that the `in >> ws` can be really useful whereas the `ignore()` function can be totally un-weildy.