# cin >> ws vs cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')?

Tags: c++, cin

From reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws, it seems like doing `cin >> ws` accomplishes what `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` was meant to do (discard leading whitespace and the newline character).

Is there any other difference that I am not taking into consideration? I am curious as to why `cin >> ws` isn't more commonly used or as popular as the much more complicated `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` which needs `#include <limits>` as well.

The only other question that I found asking this question is: 
[cin, getline, leading whitespace: ignore vs ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331385/cin-getline-leading-whitespace-ignore-vs-ws) and it hasn't gotten much attention.

Comment: Please, edit the title of your question to make it descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) discards *all* characters until the delimiter, not only white-space.

Second of all, `ignore` discards until the specified delimiter character, which could be any character (not only newline) while [`ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) ignore leading space, until there's any *non-space* character.

Third of all, newline `'\n'` is a white-space character so would be discarded by the `ws` manipulator.